# Express: req.query is always empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a file that roughly looks like this:

```js
const
    express = require('express'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app);

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'./pub')));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    
    app.get('/', (req,res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./index.html'));
    });
    app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.query); //returns empty object even though it shouldn't
        // does other stuff here
    });
    
    server.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('server is listening on port: 3000');
    });
```

Calling foo.bar/test.html?query=foobar returns an html login form that sends the request to the /test route on submit - and I'd expect the output of the console.log above to be { query: "foobar }, but it's empty.

Everything else in the app works as intended (the request for the login, saving the session, etc) with the exception of the query string.

The request form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/test" method="POST">
    <fieldset>

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type ="email" id="email" name="email"        placeholder="abc@example.com" required>

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>

        <button type ="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the request be `foo.bar/test?query=foobar` ? Like this, it points to the html file which is statically served..

Comment: The test.html file is basically a login form that performs a request to the test route. The route correctly receives the request, the user can log in and the session is saved correctly. The only thing that's weird with the request it receives is that the query is empty. The correct URL _is_ in the req.rawHeaders for example, but it would be pretty unreliable to filter the rawHeaders array for the URL and then filter the query...

Comment: Show the request code please.

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

When doing a request using a `html` form, the props can be accessed using `req.body` . The data is not sent using `querystring` (so it's not added to the url) but added to the request payload.

Here's code to read out the data from request.

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log('in login:')
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); // use req.body since there's no querystring.
    res.status(200).send('Login succeeded for user ' + req.body.email)
});
```

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry - I edited the variable & file names to simplify/censor the code and forgot to rename the /login to /test, I've fixed the question now. What I want to access is the query string from the URL though.

Comment: I fixed the answer aswell ;)

Comment: If I call `foo.bar/test.html?query=foobar`, I should be able to access the `query=foobar` part with req.query (but it's just an empty object), or am I missing something?

Comment: When you do a request using `fetch` OR `xhttp` Request to the url `foo.bar/test?query=foobar` (note no .html...) Then you should be able to access `req.params.query`. But with forms it does not work. Forms will always put the data into request payload when doing `POST`. I don't get your question.

Comment: As you can probably tell, I'm pretty new to express and handling the requests, but I understood what you meant now. I'll try to change my code so I can call `foo.bar/test?query=foobar` without .html tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible solutions that you can try:

Make sure when you test the API, you use **POST** method since you have used **POST** method in the route.

Also, the API URL should be of the form `http://localhost:3000/user?name=Karliah`. This should print `{ name : 'Karliah'}`

Comment: It is a post method (I've added an html code snippet to the question :) ), basically I just call the html document that has a login form and the /login request is called on submit, so I think the URL is correct the way it was? Removing the .html in the URL gives me the error "Cannot GET /test"

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.get('/test', (req,res) => {
    app.set('source', req.query.source);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./pub/test.html'));
});
```

Inserting this to the file mentioned in the question adds a "source" variable that can be accessed in the POST request:

```js
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.app.get('source')); //returns the value
    // does other stuff here
});
```

The URL I call does not use the .html anymore:
before: foo.bar/test.html?source=123
after: foo.bar/test?source=123